# Gradle unable to run JUnit tests with useJUnitPlatform()

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, junit, junit5

My project is a Gradle dependent JavaFX project using Java JDK 11. The project was made using the default structure of a Gradle project. So under src it has "main" and "test", each consisting of a "java" and a "resource" directory.

For setting up a CI pipeline with Jenkins it is a requirement that *gradlew test* runs all tests in the same way my IDE (IntelliJ) so far has. The funny thing is, I have not been able to get this to work after hours of trying.

[In the IntelliJ run configuration it tests "all in package", within the .test package, and this works just fine (click for screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xCJ0.png) Below are all the relevant parts of the build.gradle file, please note that I have left out all unrelated parts for simplicity.

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.1.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

application {
    mainClassName = 'FP.EDM.main/edm.Main'
}
```

Whenever I run the gradlew test command I get the following two errors:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to parse --add-opens <module>/<package>: FP.EDM.main/
```

```
Could not write standard input to Gradle Test Executor 1.
java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:354)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.forwardContent(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:67)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.run(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Another approach I have tried is to use the useJUnit() command instead of useJUnitPlatform(). At first sight this seems to work perfectly fine however when I use this no tests are found at all. My assumption is that the default module for tests is not set correctly. However I have found no way to set this or no mention of this anywhere online. Please let me know what your thoughts are :)

PS. I would much rather not downgrade to JUnit 4.x since that would require me to rewrite all these (working) tests.

Comment: The error message suggests a problem with java instrumentation/options due to the usage of modules. Given you’re using the latest Gradle version - try it first if you haven’t - more information concerning your project setup is required. I suggest you create a public repo/project with a minimal failing setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I solved the issue, I'm not quite sure what exactly caused it but it had something to do with the module-info for both the main and test modules. I decided to remove both for the time being and it runs like it should.

Edit:
After days of looking around I got it figured out at last. Adding a `module-info.java` encapsulates a module and it's dependencies. Because this project [applies the gradle-modules-plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin/blob/cfea3deb56b241216901a65b210e3dc5349166b7/src/main/java/org/openjfx/gradle/JavaFXPlugin.java#L43) I wouldn't recommend using [the same plugin again](https://github.com/java9-modularity/gradle-modules-plugin) as it could cause issues though I have not experimented with this myself.

What is the way to go then? Well there are two options:

-Ignore the module-info.java > this can be done in the build.gradle file, [for an example of that solution have a look at this](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-exclude-certain-java-files-from-being-compiled/5287)

-Specify a module-info.test > this is a way to apply certain dependencies, mine looks like the following:

```
--add-modules
        org.junit.jupiter.api

--add-reads
        FP.EDM.main=org.junit.jupiter.api
```

Please do keep in mind: this file format should go in the root of your source, all my test files were in a different directory in the root, as I didn't get it to work in the root (though that could just be me).

For further reading there is [this Git issue which helped me solve it in the first place](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/2111) or [this excellent blog by Sormuras which explains a lot](https://sormuras.github.io/blog/2018-09-11-testing-in-the-modular-world.html)