# Gradle can't access classes defined in module src/main from src/test with JavaFX plugin

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, junit, java-module

I am trying to allow my test classes to access the main classes (in a standard gradle setup). It was working fine until I put my main classes in a module (for JavaFX), at which point all tests stopped working. The main code runs fine.

If I understand correctly, according to [this gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#whitebox_unit_test_execution_on_the_classpath), doing nothing should run the tests normally, but I get an error:

```
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.TestSuiteExecutionException: Could not complete execution for Gradle Test Executor 1.
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory (in unnamed module @0x50650eec) cannot access class org.junit.platform.commons.util.Preconditions (in module org.junit.platform.commons) because module org.junit.platform.commons does not export org.junit.platform.commons.util to unnamed module @0x50650eec
```

This happens if I use the intellij configuration, or run `./gradlew test`.

So I attempted to fix the issue by [patching the module-info](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_testing_modular_patching), but then I get hundreds of errors like this one:

```
error: cannot find symbol
import snake.Snake
            ^
  symbol:   class Snake
  location: package snake
```

Which IntelliJ explains with `Package 'snake' is declared in module 'snakegame', which does not export it to module 'snakegame'`. I'm guessing that it's referring to the original module-info.java which is defined in src/main/java, and the secondary module-info.java in src/test/java.

In the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_testing_modular_patching) it had a code snippet for adding the patch argument yourself in the build.gradle, however this just results in this error:

```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error: --patch-module specified more than once for module snakegame
```

The command which was actually executed looks like this:

`compiler args for task compileTestJava: [--patch-module, snakegame=/project/path/snake/build/classes/java/main, --module-path, ... , --add-modules, org.junit.jupiter.api, --add-reads, snakegame=org.junit.jupiter.api, --patch-module, snakegame=/project/path/snake/src/test/java]`

So it's patching two different modules, which I don't understand. It doesn't really matter to me how, I just need the classes to be runnable and have access to the main classes.

### **UPDATE:**

So I recreated the project to try to create a minimal reproducible example and added in elements one at a time, and the problem didn't show up until I added in the gradle JavaFX plugin, at which point it stopped working.

So I started with the default structure, simply created a package called `example` with an `Example.class`, and created the same package in test, with a test class `Example_Test.class` with one test that creates an Example object. I then added an empty module-info in main. Original build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}
// default stuff
```

So at this point, everything is working fine. Then I change this to:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
}
```

And everything stops working

Comment: Does [this documentation help](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_modular)? Particularly example 4.

Comment: Could we get a [mcve] please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred solution would be to use a test module-info.java or module-info.test, but I was not able to get this to work. I ended up [simply ignoring modules](https://github.com/java9-modularity/gradle-modules-plugin#fall-back-to-classpath-mode) for tests, which is a terrible workaround, but works for the moment. To ignore modules during testing, add this to the build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
    // other plugins
}

// other stuff

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    moduleOptions {
        runOnClasspath = true
    }
}
```

Set `moduleOptions { runOnClasspath = true }` in `test`

Useful links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58854685/12393574
- https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/2111#issuecomment-557925312
- https://sormuras.github.io/blog/2018-09-11-testing-in-the-modular-world.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58990250/12393574
- The JavaFX plugin adds the [gradle-modules-plugin](https://github.com/java9-modularity/gradle-modules-plugin)